# Problem with Text file being overwritten instead of saving

Tags: java, text-files

I have a text file, by which I am trying to write to in my program. Whenever user wants to add a book to a library catalog, the book details will be saved to the text file. The problem is that my program successfully writes to the text file, but it only overwrites the first line over and over again if I try to add another book.

I have an ArrayList that inherits from a Book class, which contains the specific attributes of a book (title, author, publisher,etc.)

In my current program, I have created a variable called *bookInfo* that stores the String and int values of the book attributes from their respective jTextFields. I believe that it is a "class variable" (but I may be wrong) because I initialize it to the book class's constructor

```
Book bookInfo = new Book(bookTitle, author, publisher, brandCallNumber, numberOfCopies);
```

This variable is then added to the arrayList, and I call the WriteToFile() method in my program.

The code for the **AddBookDialog** class

```
public class AddBookDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
/**
 * Creates new form AddBook
 */
public AddBookDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}

               

private void jButtonSaveToLibraryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    String bookTitle = jTextFieldTitle.getText();
    String author = jTextFieldAuthor.getText();
    String publisher = jTextFieldPublisher.getText();
    String brandCallNumber = jTextFieldBranchCallNumber.getText();
    int numberOfCopies = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldCopies.getText());
    
    Book bookInfo = new Book(bookTitle, author, publisher, brandCallNumber, numberOfCopies);
    
    books.add(bookInfo);
    
    WriteToFile();
    this.setVisible(false);
}                                                    

private void WriteToFile()
{
    WriteFile wf = new WriteFile("BookDetails.txt");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
    {
     Book b = books.get(i);
     String bookDetails = b.getBookTitle() + " : " + b.getAuthorName() + " : " + b.getPublisherName() + " : " + b.getBranchCallNumber() + " : " + b.getNumberOfCopies();
     
     wf.write(bookDetails);
    }
    wf.close();
}
```

Code for **WriteFile** class

```
public class WriteFile{
private FileOutputStream filename;

public WriteFile(String inputfilename)
{
    try
    {
        filename = new FileOutputStream(inputfilename,false);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
 }

 public void write(String item)
 {
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(filename);
    output.println(item);
 }

 public void close()
 {
    try
    {
        filename.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
}
```

What I expect my program to do is to continuously add on to the text file. If I add another book, then the text file's contents should consist of

> Harry Potter : JK Rowling : Scholastic : FIC Rowl : 14
>
> Hamlet : William Shakespeare : Penguin : FIC Shak : 23

Instead, when I try to write another book to the file, it instead overwrites the first line

> Hamlet : William Shakespeare : Penguin : FIC Shak : 23
>
> //The book details for Harry Potter are overwritten

Comment: `FileOutputStream(inputfilename,false);` - do you know what this `false` means ?

Comment: I think that this could be the source of my error. According to this site(http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/fileoutputstream.html), there is a comment that states that false overwrites the file

Comment: I suggest that you use javadocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html):

> public FileOutputStream(File file,
>                           boolean append) throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.

The second argument (`boolean append`) is used to control whether to append to existing file instead of override it.

So in your case, you should pass `true` as your second argument